# R - count occurrences without melting data

Tags: r, count, sum

I am trying to simply count to values of a `wide` dataset but *without* having to transform the dataset into a `long` (Person-Period) file.

My data looks like this :

```
     alone1    alone2        alone3        alone4        alone5        alone6        alone7        alone8
 1 Mentioned Mentioned     Mentioned     Mentioned     Mentioned     Mentioned     Mentioned     Mentioned
 2 Mentioned Mentioned     Mentioned     Mentioned     Mentioned     Mentioned     Mentioned     Mentioned
 3 Mentioned Mentioned Not mentioned Not mentioned Not mentioned Not mentioned Not mentioned Not mentioned
 4 Mentioned Mentioned Not mentioned Not mentioned Not mentioned Not mentioned Not mentioned Not mentioned
```

What I want to do is this

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) 

dt %>% gather %>% group_by(value) %>% summarise(n = n())
```

Which gives me (this is the **output** I want)

```
          value  n
1     Mentioned 20
2 Not mentioned 12
```

However, I do not want to `melt` or `gather` my data.

Any idea how I could simply count the occurrences of the columns without having to do a Person Period transformation ?

```
 dt = structure(list(alone1 = c("Mentioned", "Mentioned", "Mentioned", 
"Mentioned"), alone2 = c("Mentioned", "Mentioned", "Mentioned", 
"Mentioned"), alone3 = c("Mentioned", "Mentioned", "Not mentioned", 
 "Not mentioned"), alone4 = c("Mentioned", "Mentioned", "Not mentioned", 
 "Not mentioned"), alone5 = c("Mentioned", "Mentioned", "Not mentioned", 
 "Not mentioned"), alone6 = c("Mentioned", "Mentioned", "Not mentioned", 
 "Not mentioned"), alone7 = c("Mentioned", "Mentioned", "Not mentioned", 
 "Not mentioned"), alone8 = c("Mentioned", "Mentioned", "Not mentioned", 
 "Not mentioned")), .Names = c("alone1", "alone2", "alone3", "alone4", 
 "alone5", "alone6", "alone7", "alone8"), class = "data.frame", row.names =  c(NA, 4L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It you really just need the counts you can use `table` and `unlist` your `data.frame`

```
table(unlist(dt))

Mentioned Not mentioned 
       20            12
```

Comment: thanks nice simple solution